# Как измерить насколько та или иная функция загружает процессор?

Tags: python, производительность

Заметил что мой скрипт в ходе своего выполнения буквально на 1 секунду повышает загруженность процессора (смотрел в программе FPSMonitor), есть ли способ узнать сколько та или иная функция загружает процессор в момент своего выполнения?

Comment: Возможно, этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44638140/7485582) вам поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измерить загрузку процессора можно с помощью библиотеки `psutil`.

Через `psutil.Process()` получаем текущий процесс, через `psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)` получаем число ядер. Поскольку вычисление ведется на ядро процессора. Через `pid.cpu_percent(interval=1.0)` получаем загрузку процессора, деля ее на `cpu_count`.

```
import threading
import time
import psutil
import random

def test_measure():
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        tab = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(1000000)]
        s = set(tab)
        count += 1
    return s & s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=test_measure)
    t1.start()
    pid = psutil.Process()
    time_end = time.time() + 20  # + 20 seconds
    cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)
    while time.time() < time_end:
        print(pid.cpu_percent(interval=1.0)/cpu_count)
    t1.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

> есть ли способ узнать сколько та или иная функция загружает процессор
> в момент своего выполнения?

Вопрос не очень корректен. Потому, что нагружают процессор не **функции** программы, а **процессы**. И ядро ведёт статистику нагрузки именно по **процессам**.

Подозреваю, что на самом деле, вас интересует просто вопрос о том, какая из функций Вашей программы жрёт процессорное **время** больше других функций.

Получить ответ на этот вопрос довольно просто. Предположим, что в Вашей программе работают три функции: *F1(), F2()* и *F3()*.

Для начала, заведём глобальный хэш:

```
total = dict(F1=0, F2=0, F3=0)
```

После этого, в начале тела **кажой** функции добавляем строку вида:

```
timeStart = time.time_ns()
```

Разумеется, не забываем про *import time* !  А в конце всех функций добавляем строки вида (это для F1);

```
timeEnd = time.time_ns()
duration = timeEnd - timeStart
total['F1'] += duration
```

Ну а в самом конце программы вставляем строчку вида:

```
print(total)
```

и анализируем полученные результаты.

Comment: Я понимаю, что процессор нагружает не сама функция а процессы которые протекают в ней, но я не совсем понимаю, как время затраченное на выполнение функции, скажет мне о том, из за какой части кода нагружает процессор? Дело в том, что хоть и подскакивает нагрузка процессора, но время затраченное на выполнение функции минимально и врятли отличается от такого же времени других функций.

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко -"не сама функция а процессы которые протекают в ней,"
- В функции **нет** и не может быть никаких **процессов**.

Сформулируйте вопрос корректно.

Comment: @Sergey то что одна функция потратила `n` секунд, а вторая `n/10` секунд, не означает, что первая сожрала в 10 раз больше CPU. Она могла все это время ждать на операции ввода-вывода, т.е. потреблять 0% CPU. Так что метод с подсчетом времени по часам - не годится.

Comment: @RomanKonoval - "метод с подсчетом времени по часам - не годится." - Какого **времени**?  Я говорил о **реальном** времени, потраченном на выполнение функции. Вы говорите о **процессорном** времени. Что бы узнать процессорное время, потраченное на выполнение **процесса**, есть системный вызов *time()*. Но **не существует** системного вызова, который Вам даст время, потраченное процессором на выполнение **функции** внутри процесса.  Ядро не ведёт такую статистику.